# How to append a button when already appending a row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, append

I am appending a row in HTML table using java script. I also need to append a button as one of the Table data of the row. That button should have on click event as well. how to do so? I cant get results out from any previous answers Please help. Below is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/UserApi/',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              
                alert('User Added Successfudly');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                         $("#absa").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].user_Name + "</td><td>" + data[i].Address + "</td><td>" + data[i].Email + "</td><td>" + data[i].MobileNo + "</td><td><button onclick="update()"/></td></tr>");
                }
            },
            error: function () { alert('User not Added'); }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You need to escape double quotes with backslash on `onclick="update()"` => `onclick=\"update\"`

Comment: this helped much and is something really new :) thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass event function as a string.
Dom will handle it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/UserApi/',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                alert('User Added Successfudly');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                         $("#absa").append("<tr><td>" + data[i].user_Name + "</td><td>" + data[i].Address + "</td><td>" + data[i].Email + "</td><td>" + data[i].MobileNo + "</td><td><button onclick='update()'/></td></tr>");
                }
            },
            error: function () { alert('User not Added'); }
        });

    });
```

Updated

```
<button onclick='update()'/>
```